# Encoding Problem while saving a txt file in utf-8

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

The follwing line

```
Files.write(Paths.get("test.txt"), Arrays.asList("ü"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

should write a `ü` in test.txt encoded in utf-8- At least this is what I expect it to do. But if I open the file in a text editor, the editor shows

```
Ã¼
```

and the editor states that it would read the file as utf-8. I even tried two editors and both show the same unexpected result.
A HEX-Editor shows

```
c3 83 c2 bc 0d 0a
```

The last four bytes are line feed and carriage return, that's ok, but the first two bytes should have been  `c3 bc`... since this should be the hex-encoding of `ü` in UTF-8 (according to https://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/)

The java-file is encoded in UTF-8, confirmed by two editors.

What am I missing? Why is the `ü` not encoded in utf-8 even though I explicitly passed the charset to `Files.write()`?

Comment: Try instead of `"ü"` the ASCII u-encoding: `"\u00FC"`. If that suddenly works it means that the _editor_ uses an other encoding (UTF-8)  than the _javac_ compiler (Cp1252). By the way: `, StandardCharsets.UTF_8` is default.

Comment: `\u00FC` works. Mmh where do I set the encoding for the compiler in intellij idea?

Comment: It is weird that IntelliJ uses two _different_ encodings. Is it a maven or gradle project?

Comment: In maven: `<properties><project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding></properties>`

Comment: I'ts gradle. I've set `tasks.compileJava { options.encoding = "UTF-8" }` but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: And it does not work for `ü`? It should AFAIK. https://gist.github.com/rponte/d660919434d094bbd35a1aabf7ef1bf0 does it a bit different

Comment: I didn't configure the encoding for `compileTestJava` only for `compileJava`. That's the reason. THX! If you add this as an answer, I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead of "ü" the ASCII u-encoding: "\u00FC". If that suddenly works it means that the editor uses an other encoding (UTF-8) than the javac compiler (Cp1252). By the way: , StandardCharsets.UTF_8 is default.

The java source was saved in the editor as UTF-8, two bytes with high bit set.
The java compiler javac compiled with encoding Cp1252 (probably) and turned the two bytes in two chars, which as UTF-8 summed up to 4 bytes.

So the compiler encoding had to be set.
In this case also for the *test* sources.